# VB.net XPath Not getting NodeList

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I have an XML doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Root xmlns="u" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="/xml/abc.xsd">
    <DOCID>123456789</DOCID>
    ...
    <Body>
        <Problems>
            <Problem>Data1
            </Problem>
            <Problem>Data2
            </Problem>
            <Problem>Data3
            </Problem>
        </Problems>
    </Body>
</Root>
```

I am trying to get the list of problems in the XML document above. I am using `.SelectNodes` to get the nodes. See the following code:

```
Private Sub GetProblems(ByVal xml As XmlDocument)
            Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = xml.SelectNodes("/Root/Body/Problems/Problem")
For Each node As XmlNode In nodeList
  ...
Next
End Sub
```

The `nodeList`variable has a count of 0. I used a free online XPath Tester and used the path above and it worked, but it is not working in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your XML uses a namespace, so you need a `XmlNamespaceManager`
2. Your XPATH needs to include the namespace ("u:")
3. The text contents are a node by themselves, so you want to add `/text()` to your XPATH

   ```
   Dim xdc As New XmlDocument
   xdc.Load("Myfilename.xml")
   Dim strXPATH As String = "/u:Root/u:Body/u:Problems/u:Problem/text()"
   Dim nsmgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(xdc.NameTable)
   nsmgr.AddNamespace("u", xdc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
   Dim xnl As XmlNodeList = xdc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(strXPATH, nsmgr)
   For Each xnd As XmlNode In xnl
     MsgBox(strXPATH & "=" & xnd.Value)
   Next
   ```